# How to scrape socket.io updates to a third-party site?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I basically want to know if its possible to use Socket.io using the server-side only with no client side? BUT I want to know if my server-side can instead connect with a different site that I cannot use Socket.io to connect to.

Comment: Your question is "can I give information to a person, but so that there is no *person*". It makes no sense

Comment: no I mean for example I want to get information from a site connecting through socket.io without having to have a client side.

Answer (score 0):

Use PhantomJS to load the third-party site and then inject your own javascript into the page to catch events and send those events back to your own server.

Comment: What if you can't talk to the other server, but just stream their client side??

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You need control of both servers in order to setup a communications link between them.

Comment: I'm basically trying to basically stream a site then scrape it. In that case I wouldn't be able to access their server? I want to stream it for any updates they make to the site.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.io` is a two-way connection.  Client <--> Server.  You must have a socket.io endpoint at both ends to even establish a connection in the first place.  And, then once you establish the connection, you must have agreed upon messages that can be exchanged between the two ends for it to do anything useful.

It is not useful to have a server-side socket.io that doesn't actually connect to anything and nothing connects to it.  It wouldn't be doing anything, just sitting there waiting for someone to connect to it.

It is possible to have two cooperating servers connect to one another with socket.io (one server just acts like a client in that case by initiating the connection to the other server).  But, again both endpoints must participate in the connection for the connection to even be established and certainly for it to do anything useful.

---

If you just want to download the contents of a site for scraping purposes, then you would not use socket.io for that.  You would just use the nodejs http module (or any of several other modules built on top of it).  Your server would essentially pretend to be a browser.  It would request a web page from any random web server using HTTP (not socket.io).  That web server would return the web page via the normal HTTP request.  Your receiving server can then do whatever it wants with that web page (scrape it, whatever).